# Can I buy an option that have zero price?

Tags: options, online-trading

If the option price in market is zero, Can I buy it ?
[image]

Comment: Please add some screenshots.

Comment: What is the ask price? What is the ask size?

Comment: Why would anyone *sell* you an option with zero price? There would be no way for them to profit from that.

Comment: @Philipp - "Why would anyone sell you an option with zero price?"  You own a long option that expires in January. It's late December and it's worthless with a zero bid because it's deep OTM. You want to STC so you can deduct the loss on this year's taxes. With a zero bid, there's no way to sell it. You could offer to sell it at $0.01 but the relevant question is, "Why would anyone buy this worthless option for one cent?"  The only way to do that is to combine it with another option in a spread, allowing the market maker to make the B/A spread and then STC the new leg. And yes, I've done this.

Comment: is edit question make it like a new question? I mean it is old and answered question, I just made a little editing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My broker requires a minimum price of $0.01 for single-leg option trades, even if the bid/ask shows 0/0.x

For multi-leg option trades, you can select "even" instead of credit/debit but you might still need to pay commission.

Comment: Agree 100% with that answer. Also, single leg that is truly zero cost means there should be zero probability for this to end up in the money.

Comment: @AKdemy do you mind upvoting the answer, since you agree?

Answer (score 1):

You can't buy or sell an option for zero dollars.  At best, it's a one cent minimum.

If the purpose of buying this option is to close an existing position, perhaps for tax purposes, you can use a spread order where this option is the long leg.  That will leave you with a different short leg which you will close as soon as you get a fill on your spread.